# Display datetime from json without formatting to locale timezone in javascript with moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs, angular-moment

Get following date from JSON response: 1470995100000
But angular-moment will convert this long to the current date + timezone offset. How can i avoid this?

```
{{ item.startDate | amDateFormat:'HH:mm' }}
```

Should be = 07:55 (correct value from database - always based on local timezone).
But for example 09:55 will be displayed (if the timezone on the local machine was changed)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `1470995100000` is a representation that is the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), corresponding to `2016-08-12T09:45:00Z`.

Assuming `9:55` was a typo and you meant `9:45`, then you simple are asking for your code to display the UTC time.

While fizbuszene's answer is correct from a moment.js perspective, your question was about the [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library's declarative form.  You simply need to use their `amUtc` filter, [as shown in the documentation](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amutc-filter).

```
{{ item.startDate | amUtc | amDateFormat:'HH:mm' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried moment.utc(...) ?

Comment: myApp.run(function(amMoment) {
     amMoment.changeTimezone("Europe/Berlin");
)};

solved my problem.

Comment: @Benni - Berlin is UTC+1 or UTC+2 depending on summer time.  For the value you provided, Berlin would be `2016-08-12T11:45:00+02:00`, which is not what you asked for in the question.